# Failed when using Open IAB Unity on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Android and iOS in Unity and I have used Open IAB plugin (ver 0.9.8.3) to get in-app purchase. I had done it well on Android, but when I switched to iOS plaform and built with Xcode, something went wrong with my game.

When the game changed to the purchase scene, it force closes (in Android platform, it just continue to show in-app purchase board). I built 2 other projects (1 is Open IAB sample project, 1 is a project made with only Open IAB plugin 0.9.8.3), but they return the same result.

So could I be wrong at configuring the Xcode settings? Or is it a bug of Open IAB plugin?

Hope you will reply soon! And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added StoreKit Framework Reference in your project?

Comment: yesh i had add. Found the first solution is add "-ObjC" on Other Linker Flags, and it show in-app purchase successfull on iOS 7, 8. But when i build on iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 9.1), it crash again.